# Automorphisms of a neighborhood of a negative curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ e a smooth complex surface and let $C\subset X$ be a smooth rational curve with negative self intersection.

Is there any known description of the automorphisms of the germ of manifold $(X,C)$?

More precisely: Is there any known description of the automorphisms of a infinitesimal neighborhood of $C$ in $X$? Note that it is the same as a infinitesimal neighborhood of the zero section of the normal bundle of $C$, by Grauert's theorem.

Comment: Can you define the automorphism group if the germ of manifolds? Is this the automorphism group of the total space of the normal bundle?

Comment: @NickL It is the group of the equivalence classes of map germs  $F\colon U \to V$, where $U$ and $V$ are arbitrary neighborhoods of $C$. It is not  the automorphism group of the normal bundle but only of a (infinitesimal) neighborhood of its zero section.

Comment: If we assume $X$ is quasi projective, then the curve can be blown down to a point and the automorphisms descend to the blown down surface. If you are only interested in the formal neighborhood, the ring of germs have a simple description. It is the ring of invariants of the diagonal action of the cyclic group of order $n$, where $-n$ is the self-intersection of $C$, on $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$. So, at least theoretically, there should be a nice description of its automorphisms.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for the comment. If you could explain it better in an answer I'd gladly accept it. I tried to follow this path  of contracting the curve but I could not find a systematic way to describe these automorphisms. The formal neighborhood is not what I aim but it is closer.